# Сборщик мусора собрал делегат который передавался в неуправляемый код, как этого не допустить?

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора, pinvoke

В общем, отлаживал библиотеку. решил поставить музыку которая идет в потоке на паузу, и отойти на минут 10. Пришел, и увидел нечто невероятное для меня... При продолжении воспроизведения, неуправляемая библиотека попыталась вызвать делегат, который я передавал ей, и при попытке продолжить воспроизведение потока, вылетело исключение о том, что неуправляемая библиотека попыталась вызвать делегат который был собран сборщиком мусора.

Как избежать сборки этого переданного делагата?

Код базового класса:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate void FreeDelegate(IntPtr cObjectPtr);

internal abstract class CObject : ICObject
{
    private FreeDelegate _free;

    protected CObject(IntPtr cObjectPtr, FreeDelegate freeDelegate, Action afterObjectIsSet = null)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Zero == cObjectPtr)
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(cObjectPtr));
        }

        CObjectPtr = cObjectPtr;
        _free = freeDelegate ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(freeDelegate), "freeDelegate cannot be NULL!");

        afterObjectIsSet?.Invoke();

        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    public IntPtr CObjectPtr { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

    public bool IsInvalid => IntPtr.Zero == CObjectPtr;

    public static implicit operator IntPtr(CObject currentObject)
    {
        return currentObject.CObjectPtr;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!IsDisposed)
        {
            _free?.Invoke(CObjectPtr);

            if (disposing)
            {
                _free = null;
                CObjectPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            IsDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~CObject()
    {
        Dispose(false);
#if DEBUG
        Debug.WriteLine("[{0}] -> ~CObject(), Collected by GC.", this);
#endif
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Как видно, в конструкторе вызывается `KeepAlive`.

Далее, представлю объект класса-наследника, метод которого передается в неуправляемый код:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal sealed class Media : CObject, IMedia
{
    private readonly IntPtr _mediaEventManager;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        DetachEvents();
        NativeMethods.Media.Release(this);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    internal Media(CObject factory, string location, bool isLocal = false) :
        this(factory, location.ToCString(), isLocal)
    {
    }

    private Media(IntPtr instance, IntPtr pszMrl, bool isLocal) :
        this(NativeMethods.Media.New(instance, pszMrl, isLocal), () => pszMrl.FreeCString())
    {
    }

    internal Media(IntPtr mediaPtr, Action postAction = null) :
        base(mediaPtr, NativeMethods.Media.Release, postAction)
    {
        _mediaEventManager = NativeMethods.Media.GetEventManager(this);
        AttachEvents();
        NativeMethods.Media.Retain(this);
    }

    private unsafe void AttachEvents()
    {
        for (EventType i = EventType.MediaSubItemTreeAdded; i >= EventType.MediaMetaChanged; i--)
        {
            NativeMethods.EventManager.Attach(_mediaEventManager, i, EventHandler);
        }
    }

    private unsafe void DetachEvents()
    {
        for (EventType i = EventType.MediaSubItemTreeAdded; i >= EventType.MediaMetaChanged; i--)
        {
            NativeMethods.EventManager.Detach(_mediaEventManager, i, EventHandler);
        }
    }

    private unsafe void EventHandler(Event* e, IntPtr userData)
    {
        switch (e->Type)
        {
            case EventType.MediaMetaChanged:
                OnMetaChanged(new MediaMetaChangedEventArgs(e->Data.Media.MetaChanged.MetaType));
                break;
            case EventType.MediaSubItemAdded:
                OnSubItemAdded(new MediaSubItemAddedEventArgs(new Media(e->Data.Media.SubItemAdded.NewChild)));
                break;
            case EventType.MediaDurationChanged:
                OnDurationChanged(new MediaDurationChangedEventArgs(e->Data.Media.DurationChanged.NewDuration));
                break;
            case EventType.MediaParsedChanged:
                OnParsedChanged(new MediaParsedChangedEventArgs(e->Data.Media.ParsedChanged.NewStatus != 0));
                break;
            case EventType.MediaFreed:
                Console.WriteLine("Media {0} no more valid.", e->Data.Media.Freed.MediaPtr);
                break;
            case EventType.MediaStateChanged:
                OnStateChanged(new MediaStateChangedEventArgs(e->Data.Media.StateChanged.NewState));
                break;
            case EventType.MediaSubItemTreeAdded:
                OnSubItemTreeAdded(new MediaSubItemTreeAddedEventArgs(new Media(e->Data.Media.SubItemTreeAdded.NewItem)));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<MediaStateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged;
    public event EventHandler<MediaMetaChangedEventArgs> MetaChanged;
    public event EventHandler<MediaDurationChangedEventArgs> DurationChanged;
    public event EventHandler<MediaParsedChangedEventArgs> ParsedChanged;
    public event EventHandler<MediaSubItemAddedEventArgs> SubItemAdded;
    public event EventHandler<MediaSubItemTreeAddedEventArgs> SubItemTreeAdded;

    public Uri Location
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                sbyte* mrl = NativeMethods.Media.GetMrl(this);
                if (null == mrl)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                sbyte* mrlCpy = mrl;
                int size = 0;
                while (*mrlCpy != 0)
                {
                    mrlCpy++;
                    size++;
                }

                byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                Marshal.Copy((IntPtr) mrl, bytes, 0, size);
                return new Uri(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
            }
        }
    }

    public State State => NativeMethods.Media.GetState(this);

    public void Parse()
    {
        NativeMethods.Media.Parse(this);
    }

    public void ParseAsync()
    {
        NativeMethods.Media.ParseAsync(this);
    }

    public bool GetStats(out IMediaStats stats)
    {
        // FIXME: here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(NativeMethods.Media.GetDuration(this));
    public bool IsParsed => NativeMethods.Media.IsParsed(this) != 0;

    public ICollection<IVideoTrack> VideoTracks
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                if (!IsParsed)
                {
                    Parse();
                }

                MediaTrack** tracks = null;
                uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
                if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
                {
                    return Array.Empty<IVideoTrack>();
                }

                LinkedList<IVideoTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<IVideoTrack>();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                    IVideoTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToVideoTrack();
                    if (currentTrack is null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
                }

                NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
                return videoTracks;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<IAudioTrack> AudioTracks
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                if (!IsParsed)
                {
                    Parse();
                }

                MediaTrack** tracks = null;
                uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
                if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
                {
                    return Array.Empty<IAudioTrack>();
                }

                LinkedList<IAudioTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<IAudioTrack>();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                    IAudioTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToAudioTrack();
                    if (currentTrack is null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
                }

                NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
                return videoTracks;
            }
        }
    }

    public ICollection<ISubtitleTrack> SubtitleTracks
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                if (!IsParsed)
                {
                    Parse();
                }

                MediaTrack** tracks = null;
                uint count = NativeMethods.Media.GetTracks(this, &tracks);
                if (count == 0 || tracks == null)
                {
                    return Array.Empty<ISubtitleTrack>();
                }

                LinkedList<ISubtitleTrack> videoTracks = new LinkedList<ISubtitleTrack>();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    //TODO: please... do not edit next line... it is not possible to get NullReferenceException when we get any objects from C...
                    ISubtitleTrack currentTrack = (*(tracks + i))->ToSubtitleTrack();
                    if (currentTrack is null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    videoTracks.AddLast(currentTrack);
                }

                NativeMethods.Media.TracksRelease(tracks, count);
                return videoTracks;
            }
        }
    }

    public IMedia Duplicate()
    {
        return new Media(NativeMethods.Media.Duplicate(this));
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(MediaStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StateChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnMetaChanged(MediaMetaChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MetaChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnDurationChanged(MediaDurationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DurationChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnParsedChanged(MediaParsedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParsedChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnSubItemAdded(MediaSubItemAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubItemAdded?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnSubItemTreeAdded(MediaSubItemTreeAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubItemTreeAdded?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

В классе `Media`, метод `EventHandler` передается в неуправляемый код (неявно преобразованный в делегат). При этом, сам объект этого класса, на момент исключения, собран не был, т.к. его состояние было валидным, плюс к тому же, в окне отладки не было сообщения об уничтожении какого либо из объектов посредством вызова финализатора...

Но делегат был уничтожен. Я не понимаю что происходит.

Comment: явно указать GC.KeepAlive(делегат)

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Я не могу поставить `KeepAlive` на метод класса. При этом объект с которого передается метод как делегат, не был уничтожен, но делегат был...

Comment: Метод не может быть удален GC. Каким-то образом вы из метода получаете делегат, вот там где получен - там и добавить. Если делегат получается не явно - можно заставить с# создать делегат явно. Возможно вы путаете делегат и обьект - тогда нужно сделать GC.KeepAlive обьекту, метод которого вы используете.

Comment: Окей, для полноы картины я приведу код класса.

Comment: А ошибка на каком обьекте?

Comment: Я сейчас повторю эту же процедуру, и скажу точно, потому что еще несколько классов передают метод как делегат.

Comment: Класс CObject, в конструктор я бы так же добавил бы `KeepAlive(CObjectPtr)`после его присвоения.

Comment: Немного не понимаю для чего на свойство вешать `KeepAlive`? В общем проблема воспроизвелась, класс не трогался `GC`, но как только я нажал на пробел, и библиотека начала отправку события `Playing`, упала та же ошибка. Класс Media。

Comment: Ссылка будет храниться до места вызова `KeepAlive`. Этот метод стоит в конце конструктора - вот до туда ссылка и будет жива. Вышли из конструктора - GC может собирать мусор.

Comment: В .NET делегат - полноценный объект (класс). То есть при создании делегата метод оборачивается в класс.

Comment: Для сборщика мусора `IntPtr` - это просто число и ему пофиг, что там по ссылке находится, а поскольку других ссылок на объект вы не храните, то и удаляться он будет сборщиком мусора, как обычно. Проще всего хранить этот объект явным образом, как `CObject`, вы же этим типом оперируете.  Если не хотите явно, то используйте `SafeHandle` или `HandleRef`. А `GC.KeepAlive`, как уже сказали выше, не подойдёт, потому что он работает только внутри метода - от начала, до вызова `GC.KeepAlive`.

Comment: Немного не понимаю, почему вы мне пишите про внутренний объект класса, который будет жить пока не уничтожится его владелец... Речь шла в вопросе об уничтоженном делегате, который как я понимаю можно только при помощи GCHandle закрепить, и отслеживать, что бы он не уничтожился. А вы мне про внутренний объект зачем-то пишите.

Comment: Извиняюсь, наверное не до конца понял код. Я ведь правильно понимаю: Когда вы делаете Attach(..., EventHandler), то создаётся делегат - это отдельная полноценная сущность (экземпляр класса Delegate), который вы нигде в управляемом коде не храните. Тогда не удивительно, что он уничтожается. Сборщик мусора, видя, что никто в управляемом коде не ссылается на делегат, уничтожает его, как обычно.

Comment: Вы можете создавать делегаты явно и хранить их в локальном списке или пусть EventManager занимается хранением, что более логично. Тут главное понять, что метод != делегат. Делегат создаётся отдельно на основе информации о методе и объекте, у которого он вызывается (если это не статический класс).

Comment: Мы не видим полностю ваш код, поэтому пишем о том, что видим. В конструкторе `CObject` использован бесполезный `KeepAlive`. Вы не указали, в каком именно месте выброшено исключение. Вы не привели код, где и как создаётся экземпляр класса. Наверняка это локальная переменная - вот GC её и собирает, после того как управление покинет метод. Сделайте поле класса взамен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сохранять ссылку *на сам делегат* (а не только на объект, чей метод он вызывает) в течении всего времени, пока метод может быть вызван. То есть, этот делегат не должен быть простой локальной переменной того метода, в котором он передаётся в неуправляемый код. Это должна быть внешняя (по отношению к этому методу) переменная, например поле в каком-нибудь объекте, который гарантированно просуществует нужное время.